# Not able to download and Install IBM installer application using an iPAD( iOS 7.1)

Tags: ssl, ios7, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-appcenter

I deployed the IBM app center on IBM worklight server 6.1 and enabled the SSL by generating SSL certificate using Liberty core's common utility and updated the server.xml according to that.
When I am accessing the link https://< serverIP >:< sslPort >/appcenterconsole/inst.html
It shows SSL error **SSL certificate not matches the server URL** this is my first problem.
On chrome it shows an option to proceed anyway after that I am able to access the page which has IBM App Center installer application using my username and password.
But when I click on the link of the application to download and install the app it shows message that **Cannot connect to < serverIP >** this is my second problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generated a self-signed certificate. Per documentation, IBM Application Center does not support self-signed certificates. You need to purchase an official SSL certificate from a certificate authority. This limitation comes actually from iOS.

There is a complex workaround, but I recommend this only for testing. The workaround is not really suitable for production:

1. Generate a special self-signed certificate with CA flag set to true. This makes the certificate also a certificate authority. Note: Most instructions on the web are only valid for self-signed certificates with CA flag set to false. If you use openssl, use the options -reqexts v3_req -extensions v3_ca
2. Import this SSL certificate into your device. See [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/c_ssl_config.html%23c_ssl_config) and in its subsections for details. This should also work for 6.1 even though the documentation link is for 6.2
3. Install this certificate for your webserver and proceed as usual.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to purchase nothing, you just need to create a CA certificate with an apple mac, install it to the device and u will be allowed to download the apps, easy peasy

`openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout privateKey.key -out cerficate.crt -reqexts v3_req -extensions v3_ca`

put your domain in the name field when required.

then

`cat cerficate.crt privateKey.key > server.pem`

then

`openssl pkcs12 -export -in certificate.crt -inkey server.pem -out server.p12 -passout pass:passServerP12 -passin pass:passServer`

Then to try it out:
`openssl s_client -connect hostname:port`

Hope i could help ;D